# Augmented Reality SDK for tracking hands

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality

Hi I am looking for an AR SDK that can track hand movements, I have looked at D'Fusion from Total Immersion but I would like to see other SDK's that can work on the Android Platform.

So...what SDK's that can work on the Android platform, would be best for tracking hand movements?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can pay €€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€'s you want them?;-p

Comment: I don't have one. I don't even know if one exists. Somewhat doubtful given the state of sensors on android, namely only the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is will work completely but there is 3d tracking in the metaio sdk pro (for andorid, iOS, and windows PC) (www.metaio.com/products/sdk).  If you were using static mannequin hands, this would world.

They also have a web SDk that was "tracking hand gestures" through occlusion for a JcPenny clothing app (http://www.nickburcher.com/2010/08/jc-penney-augmented-reality-virtual.html). Depending on what you want to do, perhaps you can use that method to track hands in the metaio sdk.